# Weird problem on if statement

Tags: query-posts, advanced-custom-fields

I'm facing a weird issue trying to do what I'm going to explain now.

**Context**

**Plugins I'm using:** Custom Post Type UI / Advanced Custom Fields
Functionality: 
I have a custom post type called "vendors". Within this post type I have several custom fields made on ACF. One of these fields is Called "Promote to Homepage" which is set as a checkbox.
So the idea is simple, if that checkbox is checked show that post on the homepage.

So this seemed to work fine, but when I tried to change that "Highlighted Vendor" to another one (unchecked current, checked desired to avoid conflicts I found that the post I was setting as featured wasn't showing, nothing was shown.

I started testing then trying with other vendor posts, to find that this behavior is completely random, some of them published correctly to homepage, some others not. I tried to find out a pattern to identify what might be causing it and failed. Also tried to replicate the settings of a vendor that was failing to publish within a vendor that was publishing fine, and even setting the exact same things the vendor was still publishing.

Finally I should mention that I have a page where I'm listing some kind of "directory" where all vendors are being shown. I added a simple code to check if the "promote_to_homepage" output was correct, something like "if the checkbox is checked, say hi" and found that the posts that aren't showing on homepage, pass the test on directory page.

I'm running out of ideas about what this could be, that's why I'm trying here if someone can bring me some help.

The code I'm using in the homepage is simple:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=vendors');
while (have_posts()):the_post(); 
$featured = get_field('promote_to_homepage', $post -> ID, true);
if ($featured){?><!-- show the content here -->
<?php }; endwhile; ?>
```

That's all.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me on this.

Juan.-

Answer (score 1):

there is no third parameter for [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/), may be causing your error.

**EDIT-**

In your current code, if the 10 most recent posts don't contain a post with your meta key, you'll see nothing since you're only getting 10 posts and then filtering them. Any query that doesn't specify number of posts defaults to your reading settings, which you say was 10.

also, if this is not your page's primary loop, you should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and not `query_posts`. If it *is* your page's primary loop, you should use a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook rather than `query_posts`. basically, there's no reason to ever use `query_posts` :)

a much more efficient means of selecting your posts via `WP_Query` is to query specifically for the ones with the key rather than filtering them after the fact:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // get all of them
    'post_type' => 'vendors',
    'meta_key' => 'promote_to_homepage'
);
$homepage_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $homepage_posts->have_posts() ):
    $homepage_posts->the_post();
    // all your normal loop stuff here
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

Comment: What third parameter should I set? Not understand very well. Could you please provide me with any example?

Comment: read the documentation, you only pass name and id, there is no third parameter you're passing as `true`

Comment: @Jaypee - see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where you check if the statement is true or not.
You should have something like:

```
<?php 
query_posts('post_type=vendors');
while ( have_posts() ):the_post(); 
  $featured = get_field( 'promote_to_homepage', $post->ID, true );

  if ( $featured == 1 ){
    echo 'Checked';
  } else {
    echo 'Not Checked';
  }

endwhile; 

?>
```

The if statement could either be `$featured == true` or `$feature == 1` as i usually go with.

Comment: Thank you man for trying to help me, I have tried your suggested solution but I'm still getting the error, nothing shown :(

Comment: On your get_field you can se $post->ID is not correct, try my updated code. And if that not work try to se if you get any results from the $featured by print_r($featured); it in the loop.

Comment: `if($featured)` is the same as `if($featured == 1)` or `true`

Comment: Thanks for your help Pontus but I just copy & pasted the code and still not working. This is the weirdest issue I have faced.

Comment: Do you get anything when you print $featured ? like this print_r($featured);

Comment: By testing your code, I get all the Not Checked, but the one is actually checked is now showing up, like if the checkbox wasn't outputting anything, but on the directory page, it display as expected, showing as featured.

Comment: I just made a new template to see if the problem was on homepage, some conflict, but it is not showing either...not sure what else to do. Remember that with some of the posts it works, but with some other it doesn't, there are no identificable pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Ah looked at the codex and there is no true on the get_field:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/

```
$value = get_field( 'promote_to_homepage', $post->ID );
if( $value ) {
  echo 'Checked';
}
else {
 echo 'Not Checked';
}
```

Comment: my answer 15 minutes ago...

Comment: Didn't see that, have soo bad connection on the train...

Comment: Thanks SO much Pontus, also to you Milo, but I tested that before, and It's not working either. The parameter get_field('field_name', $post -> ID, true) is working correctly on the directory.

Comment: Pontus!!! I found something here!!!! I was thinking that maybe post wasn't showing because it was behind the pagination, and guess what. I went to Wordpress Settings, and changed the Reading Settings to show 100 posts instead 10, I'm know getting the vendor displayed. Any explanations?!!! I don't how could I get the same result without touching the amount of posts displayed (will affect other pages if I leave like that)